# How to insert a footnote in table / tabular environment?

Tags: tables, footnotes

I am trying to insert a footnote to my document. However, the footnote is on the next page. Furthermore, the numeration of the footnote is wrong as well. Specifically, I have the my table set as a `tabular` inside a `center` environment to keep the table in-place within my text.

Does anyone know, how to fix this?

```
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{rclcrcl}
   $N_V$ & = & Dimension des Eigenvektors $V$  &$\qquad$& $ V\textsubscript{k}$ &=& kter Eigenvektor der Korrelationsmatrix\\
   $p_{sub}$ & = & Signal-Unterraum  &  $\qquad$      &  $e(f)$  &=& komplexe Exponentialfunktion\tablefootnote{Dieser Term wird benötigt, um eine Fourier-Transformation mit dem Term $V\textsubscript{k}\textsuperscript{H} * e(f)$ zu ermöglichen.}\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this `tabular` of yours close to the bottom boundary of the page? Can you provide some visuals of the two pages it currently is associated with?

Comment: @Werner I added two pages. The first contains the footnote in the table (10), the second one the footnote outside the table.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble (if you haven't already) and then using `\begin{table}[H]` ... `\end{table}` instead of `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tablefootnote`](//ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) explicitly states in the [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tablefootnote) that it

> ... provides the command `\tablefootnote` to be used in a `table` or `sidewaystable` environment ...

Since you've set your `tabular` inside a `center` environment, the "delayed" printing of the actual footnote doesn't occur the way it should. Also, since `center` is probably meant as a `table`-in-place, the following solution should prove sufficient: Add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble (if you haven't already) and set the `center`ed `tabular` inside a `\begin{table}[H]`...`\end{table}` construction.

```
% <your preamble>
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

% <your in-place-table>
\begin{table}[H]
% <tabular with \tablefootnote>
\end{table}
```